# Is there any third party jar files available for java6 math evaluation?

Tags: java

I want to calculate mathematical expression in java6.for example,

```
c=a*b+((b/d)-c)/100-(h/2)
```

How to evaluate this math expression....

Please guide me get a solution...

Saravanan.P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the way, JEP can still be downloaded (through an older version, but still) as a GPL licensed library [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jep/files/) (See [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446466/java-math-expression-parser-that-can-take-complex-numbers-as-a-variable).)

** **EDIT** **

The [JEP documentation](http://www.singularsys.com/jep/doc/html/usage.html) is very well-written and contains a lot of examples.

Comment: I've never really used JEP, but the related question does have a sample example. Plus, the JEP documentation should still be compatible with the GPL version.

Answer (score 3):

[JEP](http://www.singularsys.com/jep/) is a Java expression parser library.

Answer (score 2):

Try [JEP](http://www.singularsys.com/jep/)

Answer (score 1):

i recently implemented a simple math expression evaluator on basis of [Dijkstra's Shunting Yard Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) and released it under the [Apache License 2.0](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html).

you can check it out here: http://projects.congrace.de/exp4j/index.html